# How to remove duplicate object from an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to use an autocomplete search box to search and store values into an array. My first selection functions as expected. When selecting a second item, it creates a duplicate object in the array. How can I avoid this?

```
playListSelect(item){
let hasPlaylist:boolean = false;  

for(var i= 0 ; i < this.selectedPlayListArray.length ; i++){  
    if(this.selectedPlayListArray[i].id == item.id ){
      hasPlaylist = true;
      break;
    }
}
if(hasPlaylist == false){
  this.selectedPlayListArray.push(item);
}

}
```

Comment: did you search for it first ?

Comment: one of my colleague helped me - that now its not occuring duplicate by using flag of boolean whenever select an item

Answer (score 0):

Check that if it already exist or not

```
if(this.selectedPlayListArray[i].id == item.id && this.selectedPlayListArray.indexOf(item) >-1){

     this.selectedPlayListArray.push(item);
    }
```

That skips adding if it already exist.